# "Dark, straight hair" and "Curly gray hair"

Tags: adjectives, punctuation, adjective-order

My book says "dark, straight hair" and "curly gray hair" are ways to describe physical appearance.

I've seen there's an order of adjectives people usually follow and I wonder why the book uses color + shape in one description and shape + color in the other.

Doesn't the order matter here?

Also, they separate the adjectives in the first description with a comma but not in the other.

> [image: describing physical appearance]

Comment: For what it's worth, [Google Ngrams suggests that "straight dark hair" is a lot more common than "dark straight hair".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=straight+dark+hair%2C+dark+straight+hair&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstraight%20dark%20hair%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdark%20straight%20hair%3B%2Cc0)  I feel like the comma might change things slightly.

Comment: I'd guess they used the two different sequences specifically in order to imply that (in this exact context, at least) the "Royal Order of Adjective" shouldn't be applied too rigorously (both versions are syntactically / idiomatically fine, regardless of which might be more common).

Answer (score 1):

That's what sounds easier on the ear to me:

*long straight black hair*

That comma looks suspicious though... ;-)

[Here is a useful link.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/grammaire/grammaire-britannique/adjectives-order)

Comment: I could argue they used the comma to move that adjective to the beginning as in a train of thought kind of thing.